# SASS: Perform multiple color operations?

Tags: css, sass

Using SASS, is it possible to perform multiple color operations on a single hex code? I would like to programmatically lighten and increase saturation by 5%.

```
saturate($color, $amount)
lighten($color, $amount)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can chain them together:

```
saturate(lighten($color, $amount), $amount)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it only once, just use it one after another:

```
$color: #123
$amount: 5%
$color: saturate($color, $amount)
$color: lighten($color, $amount)

.element
  background-color: $color
```

If you want to to it repeatedly, create a function:

```
@function saturate-and-lighten($color, $amount)
  $output: saturate($color, $amount)
  $output: lighten($output, $amount)
  @return $output
```

Then use it like this:

```
.element
  background-color: saturate-and-lighten(#123, 5%)
```